# What timezone is Google Cloud Monitoring using for grouping?

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

In a **Cloud Monitoring dashboard**, you have different timespans you can select. Each of them aggregates the data per **minute/hour/day/etc**.

An example:

[image: Google Cloud Monitoring Example]

The timestamps that are assigned to the x-axis seem to be in the user's timezone. However, are the **aggregates calculated based on UTC, or the user's timezone, or even something different?**

The consequence of a user's timezone would be that everyone across the globe would see a different graph. Furthermore, I cannot find any settings related to this.

After looking through the documentation, I cannot find the answer to this. Hence, any insight (preferably with a documentation reference) would help. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't found anything in the documentation either, but I think the case you are commenting on has been taken into account because it doesn't make sense to show different graphs depending on the user's timezone.

Answer (score 1):

it's been 2 years since this was asked, however, I'll leave an answer for future people's benefit.
I have configured the time zone via the menu where one changes the time period to cover, in the metrics chart section. See the red rectangle in the image below.

[image: Image with time zone option]